# how to triger testng by testng.xml, after determing by other test which testng.xml need to be run

Tags: testng

I need to run a programe before knowing which suit of test(define in testng.xml) need to be trigger.

How to solve this problem? how to trigger testNG in run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at TestNG's programmatic API?

Comment: Could you improve this answer? A novice would appreciate links to useful resources and/or examples.

Comment: Here is the documentation:  http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Below code you have to put it in main method. You can run the class as regular java file.

```
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setName("TmpSuite");
XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
test.setName("TmpTest");
List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
suites.add(suite);
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
//MyTestListener   is custom listner if any
TestListenerAdapter listener = new MyTestListener();      
tng.addListener(listener);    
tng.setXmlSuites(suites);    //if any suits      
tng.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can add listeners ie- suitelistner , testlistner and report listener for better control over your test.